# I'm getting exit status 1 Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Uno.trying to do a basic IR project

Tags: arduino, infrared

Here is the code I'm trying to run on my Arduino.

```cpp
#include "IRremote.h"

int receiver = 11; // Signal Pin of IR receiver to Arduino Digital Pin 11

/*-----( Declare objects )-----*/
IRrecv irrecv(receiver);     // create instance of 'irrecv'
decode_results results;      // create instance of 'decode_results'

void setup()   /*----( SETUP: RUNS ONCE )----*/
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("IR Receiver Button Decode"); 
  irrecv.enableIRIn(); // Start the receiver

}/*--(end setup )---*/


void loop()   /*----( LOOP: RUNS CONSTANTLY )----*/
{
  if (irrecv.decode(&results)) // have we received an IR signal?

  {
    translateIR(); 
    irrecv.resume(); // receive the next value
  }  
   }/* --(end main loop )-- */

/*-----( Function )-----*/
void translateIR() // takes action based on IR code received

// describing Remote IR codes 

{

  switch(results.value)

  {

  case 0xFF629D: Serial.println(" FORWARD"); break;
  case 0xFF22DD: Serial.println(" LEFT");    break;
  case 0xFF02FD: Serial.println(" -OK-");    break;
  case 0xFFC23D: Serial.println(" RIGHT");   break;
  case 0xFFA857: Serial.println(" REVERSE"); break;
  case 0xFF6897: Serial.println(" 1");    break;
  case 0xFF9867: Serial.println(" 2");    break;
  case 0xFFB04F: Serial.println(" 3");    break;
  case 0xFF30CF: Serial.println(" 4");    break;
  case 0xFF18E7: Serial.println(" 5");    break;
  case 0xFF7A85: Serial.println(" 6");    break;
  case 0xFF10EF: Serial.println(" 7");    break;
  case 0xFF38C7: Serial.println(" 8");    break;
  case 0xFF5AA5: Serial.println(" 9");    break;
  case 0xFF42BD: Serial.println(" *");    break;
  case 0xFF4AB5: Serial.println(" 0");    break;
  case 0xFF52AD: Serial.println(" #");    break;
  case 0xFFFFFFFF: Serial.println(" REPEAT");break;  

  default: 
    Serial.println(" other button   ");

  }// End Case

  delay(500); // Do not get immediate repeat


}
```

Here is my error message. (I think I fixed first one.)

```
Arduino: 1.8.0 (Windows 8.1), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"

C:\(my folers)
arduino\arduino\libraries\RobotIRremote\src\IRremoteTools.cpp:5:16: error: 'TKD2' was not declared in this scope

 int RECV_PIN = TKD2; // the pin the IR receiver is connected to

                ^

Multiple libraries were found for "IRremote.h"
 Used: C:\Users\Mike\Desktop\Games\Zach arduino\arduino\libraries\RobotIRremote
 Not used: C:\Users\Mike\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Arduino-IRremote-master
exit status 1
Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Uno.

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

Comment: You should not make changes to your question that invalidate an existing answer. If you have a new question you should ... well ... ask a new question.

Comment: oh. ok. this is my first post ever :| sorry. :)

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty self-explanatory: 
"Multiple libraries were found for 'IRremote.h'"

It looks like you have the same library file in two locations. Delete one and the compiler will know which one to use.

Comment: Yes, but it still used one of the libraries. Used: C:\Users\Mike\Desktop\Games\Zach arduino\arduino\libraries\RobotIRremote
 Not used: C:\Users\Mike\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Arduino-IRremote-master